# JAXB marshalling exception javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError running with Java 5

Tags: maven, xml-serialization, jaxb, jaxb2

I am trying a simple JAXB marshaling in my JUit test class and I am using Java 5. I get this error while running the test.

javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider  com.bea.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactoryBase not found

I have added the following dependencies in my pom.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr173</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
       <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

any help on this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the dependency list above, it looks like you are using [jsr173](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=173) - steaming API for XML.  The dependency you have specified just provides the API.  You need to add a provider which implements this.  The default provider that it looks for, if it does not find any is the bea implementation.  Hence the error.

Here is a [discussion](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=784383) on this.  You could add the bea implementation or alternate ones like [woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/).

Comment: [Link that helped](http://www.emmersonmiranda.net/2010/09/provider-combeaxmlstreammxparserfactory.html)

When I added the stax dependency, I was able ti run the tests with jaxb

Comment: Thanks Raghuram for the reply I believe that the required implementation is bundled with stax dependency.