# Can't run XML parser Jackson on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, jackson

Can't run XML parser Jackson on Android

```
 import android.content.Context;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.List;




in onCreate(){
    ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            Channel root = xmlMapper.readValue(stringXML, Channel.class);
}



@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "channel")
    public static class Channel {
        public List<Item> channel;
    }

    public static class Item {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "item")
        public String item;
    }
```

Error is :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory" on path: DexPathList
```

Comment: If you are asking "How to fix this error?", what is "_How to rename main Name of the project in Android Studio?_" question doing at the beginning of the post? And your code is incomplete, it won't compile. Please, create a [mcve].

Comment: @Roman, sorry, didn't delete previous question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Old question but...

Android doesn't have the `javax.xml.stream` package, which is required for most libraries involving XML.

To add this yourself, add this dependency to your build.gradle file:

`compile group: 'javax.xml.stream', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0-2'`

This is the latest release as of writing this comment. You can check [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.stream/stax-api) for updated versions.

Comment: it's really helped, Thanks

Comment: Worked for me as well. Was very frustrating to get Jackson working without this. Used to be easier, now everything's too Oracle JRE specific.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't setup Jackson for Android correctly. Look at this page [Using jackson-dataformat-xml on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360025/using-jackson-dataformat-xml-on-android). There are good description how to do it.