# Liferay: Reading Excel data using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, liferay-7

Getting the below error while reading the Excel data using Apache POI:

> javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider
>   com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found.

Below is the code I am using:

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteCodeConversion);
ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(-1.0d);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);//Throwing the error
```

Below are the dependencies I am using:

```
compile group: 'stax', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0.1'
compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.9'
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.15'
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '3.15'
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.15'
compile group: 'dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '1.6.1'
compile group: 'stax', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'
```

Comment: Take a look on the answer of [Using com.bea.xml.stream package on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968735/using-com-bea-xml-stream-package-on-android/30991206)

Comment: @samabcde I tried it previously but no luck..

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade?