# Android dependency issue - ApachePOI & fasterxml

Tags: android, android-studio, apache-poi, build.gradle, fasterxml

I'm currently developing an Android application, which is required to read/write data from/to an Excel spreadsheet (*.xls* or *.xlsx*).

In order to integrate Android <--> Excel I am using [this poi library](https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/), mainly because I was having some issues with correctly configuring the dependencies to the original [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-4.0.1).

**Note:** On an action performed (button click), a workbook object is instantiated as such `this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(super.file);`

Following is the content of my *build.gradle* (module) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ricardomiranda.expenses"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // Workaround - "Program type already present"
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    // Workaround - "com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found"
    implementation('com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'){
        // Workaround - "Program type already present"
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'support-v7'
        exclude module: 'fasterxml'
    }

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/poishadow-all.jar')
}`
```

As one can observe, the previous code snippet has some workaround inclusions (properly highlighted by the comments) in order to try to solve the problems I'm facing, yet to no avail.

### **The issues:**

Consider the previous *build.gradle* code snippet **without the workarounds**

1. The build is successfully executed and the application is launched. On a button click, the aforementioned line is executed: `this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(super.file);` as well as some other classes and methods inherited from the poi library - this button is trying to write data into an Excel spreadhseet. However, the expected behaviour is not applied, as the execution is aborted with a "fatal exception" as such:

`

```
2019-01-31 18:35:14.377 20682-20682/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ricardomiranda.expenses, PID: 20682
    org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found
        at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:72)
        at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:178)
        at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:92)
        at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newInstance(XMLEventFactory.java:30)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:41)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:130)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:295)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:201)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:323)
        at com.ricardomiranda.expenses.ExcelManagement.initializeWorkbook(ExcelManagement.java:141)
        at com.ricardomiranda.expenses.ExcelManagement.<init>(ExcelManagement.java:51)
        at com.ricardomiranda.expenses.AddExpense$1.onClick(AddExpense.java:44)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

In order to remediate the issue and based on [this comment](https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/issues/8#issuecomment-382219841), I added the following dependency to my build `implementation('com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0')` and set the required system properties (also described in the [Getting started](https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/blob/master/README.md) section of the library's README documentation).

2. Relaunching the application after applying the former changes results in the next error, this time during the project's build: 
   `Error: Program type already present: com.fasterxml.aalto.ValidationException`

As far as I can tell this seems to be a [duplicated dependency problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies), but I can't resolve `gradlew app:dependencies` (the output is way too extensive) and no configurations are outputted by analogous commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using com.bea.xml.stream package on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968735/using-com-bea-xml-stream-package-on-android)

Comment: I have indeed gone through that post but I can't manage to find a solution for my case.

Comment: Hi did you solve this ?

Comment: Hi @JimmyKane. Sadly I wasn't able to solve this issue.